# Invalid Column name Error in DSE Analytics Spark

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, datastax, spark-cassandra-connector

I have one table whose structure roughly is as follows ->

```
CREATE TABLE keyspace_name.table_name (
  id text PRIMARY KEY,
  type text,
  bool_yn boolean,
  created_ts timestamp,
  modified_ts timestamp
)
```

Recently I added new column in the table ->

```
alter table keyspace_name.table_name first_name text;
```

And when I query on the given column from table in cqlsh, it gives me the result. For eg.

```
select first_name from keyspace_name.table_name limit 10;
```

But if I try to perform the same query in dse spark-sql

It is giving me the following error.

> Error in query: cannot resolve '`first_name`' given input columns: [id, type, bool_yn, created_ts, modified_ts];

I don't know what's wrong in spark-sql. I've tried nodetool repair but problem still persists

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what version of DSE?

Comment: I'm using latest DSE 6.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If table schema changes, the Spark metastore doesn't automatically refresh the schema changes, so manually remove the old tables from spark sql with a `DROP TABLE` command, then run `SHOW TABLES`. The new table with latest schema will be automatically created. This will not change the data in Cassandra.